# Передача атрибутов одного класса другому

Tags: python, tkinter

При запуске программы получается ошибка `AttributeError: 'BD' object has no attribute 'entry_description'`. Как это можно исправить?

```
class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()    

    def init_child(self):
        BD().create()

        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)
        self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

        btn_add = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить', command = BD().add_item())
        btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
        btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
        btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


class BD:
    def create(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albums (ID integer primary key,
                                                              description text,
                                                              costs text,
                                                              total real)""")
        conn.commit()

    def add_item(self):
        cursor = sqlite3.connect('finance.db').cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
                      (self.entry_description.get(), self.combobox.get(), self.entry_money.get()))
```

Comment: где у вас конструктор класса `BD`?

Comment: У вашего класса BD и в самом деле нет никакого entry_description. И combobox тоже нет. И даже entry_money отсутствует. Передавайте все нужные данные в add_item через аргументы, например

Comment: @andreymal , не подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor почитать в любом учебнике про функции? Хотя вам вон уже в ответе написали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё довольно просто, для того чтобы получить данные для добавления в базу, вы должны их передать внутрь обьекта класса BD. В функции add, были обращений к несувществующим атибутам класса.

Вот, исправил ошибки:

```
from tkinter import StringVar

class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        BD().create()

        self.description = StringVar()
        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.description)
        self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)

        self.money = StringVar()
        self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.money)
        self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

        btn_add = tk.Button(
            self,
            text='Добавить',
            command=lambda: BD().add_item(
                self.description.get(),                    
                self.combobox.get(),
                self.money.get()
            )
        )
        btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
        btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
        btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')


        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()



class BD:
    def create(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albums (ID integer primary key,
                                                              description text,
                                                              costs text,
                                                              total real)""")
        conn.commit()

    def add_item(self, entry_description, combobox, entry_money):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
        cursor= conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
                      (entry_description, combobox, entry_money))
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: Что в вашем коде, что в коде автора add_item будет вызываться не при клике на кнопку, а сразу после запуска программы

Comment: @andreymal я зафиксил это вроде как)

Comment: @andreymal Я не вникал в код программы. Вопрос стоит в чем? "Вылетает ошибка при запуске", я пофиксил то что просил автор;)

Comment: @andreymal , спасибо за ответ. Подскажите , почему полученные данные не сохраняются в БД?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor посмотрите ответ, я обновил там функцию add_item

Comment: Методы `create` и `add_item` лучше сделать статичными, тогда не нужно будет новый объект для их вызова создавать, плюс будет убран ненужный параметр `self`

Comment: @andreymal , теперь данные добавляются , но только из поля combobox, можете с этим помочь?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor поправил ответ, попробуйте, должно работать.. и да, я не andreymal ;)

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk , теперь выдает ошибку "name 'StringVar' is not defind"

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk , моя ошибка , не импортировал stringvar

Answer (score 1):

Передачу атрибутов между классами можно сделать с помощью наследования (`2.7`):

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, x=16):
    self.y = x**2

  def add(self, ww):
    print "I am A's method" + ww

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(B, self).__init__()

  def add(self, tt):
    super(B, self).add(tt)

bb = B()
print bb.y
bb.add("!")
# 256
# I am A's method!
```

Или забрасыванием класса как атрибута:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.class_attr = z

cc = C(A(25))
print cc.class_attr.y
# 625
```

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос.. там суть немного в другом была;)

Comment: я добавил ответ полезный и другим пользователям